# Perform same operation to multiple variables, assigning result

Tags: r, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm working on a project where I have to apply the same transformation to multiple variables. For example

```
a <- a + 1
b <- b + 1
d <- d + 1
e <- e + 1
```

I can obviously perform the operations in sequence using

```
for (i in c(a, b, d, e)) i <- i + 1
```

However, I can't actually assign the result to each variable this way, since `i` is a copy of each variable, not a reference.

Is there a way to do this? Obviously, it'd be easier if the variables were merged in a data.frame or something, but that's not possible.

Comment: may be you can do `list2env(lapply(mget(ls()), "+", 1), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: In the for loop, it is `assign`

Comment: The standard approach would be to put them in a list `lst <- list(a, b, c, d, e)`, then alter this list with `lapply`, e.g. `lst <- lapply(lst, '+', 1)` adds 1 to all elements. Are you aware of this solution and intentionally choosing not to put them in a list, or does that work for you?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I had not thought of doing it with lists. Yeah, that'd probably work in this case. Feel free to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question states that the variables to increment cannot be in a larger structure but then in the comments it is stated that that is not so after all so we will assume they are in a list `L`.

```
L <- list(a = 1, b = 2, d = 3, e = 4) # test data

for(nm in names(L)) L[[nm]] <- L[[nm]] + 1

# or
L <- lapply(L, `+`, 1)

# or
L <- lapply(L, function(x) x + 1)
```

### Scalars

If they are all scalars then they can be put in an ordinary vector:

```
v <- c(a = 1, b = 2, d = 3, e = 4)
v <- v + 1
```

### Vectors

If they are all vectors of the same length they can be put in data frame or if they are also of the same type they can be put in a matrix in which case we can also add 1 to it.

## Environment

If the variables do have to be free in an environment then if `nms` is a vector of the variable names then we can iterate over the names and use those names to subscript the environment `env`.  If the names follow some pattern we may be able to use `nms <- ls(pattern = "...", envir = env)` or if they are the only variables in that environment we can use `nms <- ls(env)`.

```
a <- b <- d <- e <- 1 # test data

env <- .GlobalEnv  # can change this if not being done in global envir
nms <- c("a", "b", "d", "e")

for(nm in nms) env[[nm]] <- env[[nm]] + 1

a;b;d;e  # check
## [1] 2
## [1] 2
## [1] 2
## [1] 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually if you find yourself doing the same thing to multiple objects, they should be stored / thought-of as single object with sub-components. You say that storing these as a data.frame is not possible, so you can use a list instead. This allows you to use `lapply`/`sapply` to apply a function to each element of the list in one step.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- c(1, 4)
c <- 5
d <- rnorm(10)
e <- runif(5)

lstt <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d, e = e)
lstt$a
# [1] 1 2 3

lstt <- lapply(lstt, '+', 1)
lstt$a
# [1] 2 3 4
```